# Compile source with later libraries on one server and use the binary on an older server

Tags: ubuntu, software-installation, compiling

I need the latest `libpcre3-dev` library to compile a software from source, however, the current distribution of the OS (Ubuntu) on my server only has the older version of `libpcre3-dev` and no backport is available.

I am thinking to compile the binary on a separate server with the latest version of `libpcre3-dev` and install the binary back to my actual server. I have two questions:

1. Does this work? My main concern is that the `libpcre3` on my server is still the older version, does the binary still need the latest corresponding `libpcre3` at runtime even if it is compiled with the latest `libpcre3-dev`?
2. What is the best way of installing the binary back to my server? Simply copy the binary or make it into a `.deb` package and then install using the package manager (if possible)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the program requires newer features that aren't available on your server, then those features won't be available at runtime and so your program probably won't run.

You can link the library statically. This has the downside that you can't upgrade the library separately from the program. If a security vulnerability is found in that version of the library, you'll need to rebuild the program. Replace `-lpcre3` in the linker command line by `/usr/lib/libpcre3.a`.

You can link dynamically and copy the library to the same directory where you install your software. Start the software through a wrapper script that sets the library load path to include that additional directory.

```
#!/bin/sh
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/opt/my-software/lib"
/opt/my-software/bin/foo "$@"
```

Answer (score 1):

Your first question is really about [linking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_%28computing%29), so it depends if you link statically or not. If you do and both platforms have the same architecture, then it should work.

A good way to install a self-compiled binary is to use [checkinstall](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/checkinstall.8.html). It creates a Debian package that can be installed an uninstalled using your favorite package manager.